# Revolutions slider replace dots in scriptnames

Tags: javascript, jquery, revolution-slider

I'm using V5 of RS. By default all scriptnames look something like `revolution.extension.video.min.js`.

I'm trying to build a hero video slider into a webshop. This webshop is a SaaS solution. The system of my webshop replaces all dots in script/image/file names into dashes. Since it's possible to load the required files for video's on demand only I need to replace the dots.

I'm a bit hacking into the core files of RS to replace the default dots into dashes so my webshop can find the scripts again.

I managed to replace the last dot in the file name with a dash. Right now I have this: `revolution.extension.video-min.js`.

Does anyone know how to replace the rest of the dots? Where do I have to look for example? I can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: *The system of my webshop replaces all dots in script/image/file names into dashes.* you should better try to make an exception to that rewriting system for your js directory. anything else will bite you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found an answer to my question. @line 759 you'll find an Ajax call. 
Replacing the name there like so,

```
url:o.jsFileLocation+s.replace(/\./g,'-')+o.extensions_suffix,
```

will do the trick!